# can I manipulate contents of an observable array?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2

working with AngularFireStrore I get a collection and assign it to an observable array. then in a function activated by a button I want to modify that collection. I am trying to do it in the following way but it indicates to me that vaor is an observable type.

```
private listBonosImponibles: AngularFirestoreCollection<EmployeeBonos>;

  unBonosImponibles: Observable<EmployeeBonos[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.listBonosImponibles = this.itemDoc.collection<EmployeeBonos>('bonosImponibles');


    this.unBonosImponibles = 
    this.listBonosImponibles.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as EmployeeBonos;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });



   }
```

I successfully get my collection inside the constructor and now if I want to show the array obtained by console, it does not show anything since it does not enter the console.log add a breackpoint in it and it does not enter

```
    saveEmployee(){

      this.unBonosImponibles.map((dat: any) => {
       console.log(dat);
       this.listBonosImponibles.doc(dat.id).update(dat);
       });

      }
```

that's how I show the matrix in my view

```
<div *ngFor="let bonoImpo of unBonosImponibles | async" fxLayout="row" >
  <label fxFlex="70" >{{ bonoImpo.nombre }}</label>
  <mat-form-field class="ml-5"  >
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="bonoImpo.valor"   />
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="saveEmployee()" color="primary">Guardar</button>
```

Comment: Where is `vaor` in your example? Please give a consistent [mcve] (ideally in English, so it's easier to follow what's supposed to be happening). In general, if you want access to the array in an observable of arrays, use an observable operator like `.map`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Now modify the code, if I add map to the observable the console log inside is not running

Comment: You need to subscribe to it somewhere. If you're not returning the observable, just swap `map` for `subscribe`. You don't actually appear to be *attempting* to manipulate the array.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify the purpose of modifying the collection. Are you trying to persist the changes back through AngularFirestore? How are you getting the changes from the view?

Comment: @bygrace what I want is to go through the collection and then take the id of each document and update each document in that collection

Comment: What is the source of the updates?

Comment: @bygrace now add the code that updates the collection documents

Comment: You may find life easier if you were to subscribe to `this.listBonosImponibles.snapshotChanges()` and map the data to a public array on the class. Then on submit you can just iterate over it.

Comment: Data doesn't "live" in an observable for you to update. If you have a subject that does replay data then you can get it on subscribe but for a standard subject you just have to catch it as it flows through. Using `ngModel` on the output of an observable is probably just updating objects that you no longer have a reference to.

Comment: @bygrace Could you write an example and leave it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with AngularFirestore

The `.map` on your `this.listBonosImponibles` is creating new objects which are being bound the view but you don't keep a reference to them. So even though ngModel probably changes them you don't really have a way to access them. I think that you might find it easier to just subscribe to the observable and keep a local copy like the following:

```
private listBonosImponibles: AngularFirestoreCollection<EmployeeBonos>;

  unBonosImponibles: EmployeeBonos[];

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.listBonosImponibles = this.itemDoc.collection<EmployeeBonos>('bonosImponibles');

    listBonosImponibles.snapshotChanges().subscribe(actions => {
      this.unBonosImponibles = actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as EmployeeBonos;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Remove the async in the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let bonoImpo of unBonosImponibles" fxLayout="row" >
```

Iterate on save:

```
saveEmployee(){
  this.unBonosImponibles.forEach((dat: any) => {
    console.log(dat);
    this.listBonosImponibles.doc(dat.id).update(dat);
  });
}
```

All this code was thrown together in this editor. So I'm not saying it runs without error. It is more to show the general type of approach. I'm not saying that this is the best approach but it should get you where you want. You could go more reactive on it by introducing reactive forms but that may be more complicated than you want.